# How does Python handle importing the same module in multiple Python instances?

Tags: python, module

I created an application that has some custom modules that I am using for multiple apps (scripts). Each app runs independently on it's own scheduler and imports the same two modules that I created. One is more of a utility module and the other is the database module to handle the database connections.

The goal here is to run multiple python scripts at the same time in parallel with using the same modules to save on recoding the same things per app.

App layout is similar to:

```
-AppName
--src
---app
----App1.py
----App2.py
---module
----utility.py
----db.py
----log.py
```

In my case, there is about 10 app's that are running at the same time and importing the same two modules. It's been working fine, but recently, the apps are slowing down and I wanted to start investigating the shared modules.

**Version**

Python 2.7 on Windows

**Execution**

Each app is executed in it's own Python instance on the same server. Python lives on one virtual drive, the scripts on another. Each app is downloading, re-encoding, and uploaded GB's of data.

**Module Import Timing**

Each module takes about 3 seconds to import. Running a single app general starts within that time frame.

**Question**

How does Python handle importing the same module across multiple Python instances? A lot of questions seem to be tied to importing the same module in a single script. Not so many around the same module being imported at the same time across different scripts and different Python instances on the same machine.

My guess is Python will handle it as long as it has resources available. But, I'm seeing apps that normally take 10 seconds to load now take 1 hour to load. I'm assuming it's due to the fact that shared modules are bogging down per instance.

Comment: Soon as I posted this, I found the answer. Even if the module is imported multiple times in other instances, it's only init once unless Python can't find it in the cache. So, it's not likely the cause of failure.

Comment: Please consider migrating your comment to a full answer so that this question can be marked as closed.